# chrome started crashing all of a sundden

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I have Google chrome  3.0.195.27 installed on XP,  without any apparent change in my system setup it started crashing a few minutes after I start the application.    how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try is reinstalling Chrome.